# D3.js animate rotation

Tags: javascript, animation, rotation, d3.js, transform

I'm having trouble when I try to correctly execute a rotation animation using the D3.js library. The problem has to do with the point at which I want to rotate the element about.

Here is a fiddle I made to show what I mean (in slow motion): http://jsfiddle.net/74mCb/

It seems like the source of the problem lies here:

```
.attr("transform", "rotate(-60, 150,130)");
```

And then I rotate it like so:

```
.attr("transform", "rotate(40 150,130)");
```

I would like the butt of the needle to stay in position (to be the center of rotation), could someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is a bit tricky to grasp (I don't fully understand it myself) but D3 needs some help knowing how to interpolate between the two strings that represent your rotation.

```
function turnNeedle()
{

    needle
      .transition()
      .duration(2000)
      .attrTween("transform", tween);

    function tween(d, i, a) {
      return d3.interpolateString("rotate(-60, 150, 130)", "rotate(60, 150, 130)");
    }

}
```

`d` is the datum, `i` is the index, `a` is the attribute in case you want to make this data-driven.

http://jsfiddle.net/SHF2M/

Comment: Nice answer - possibly easier than mine :).

Comment: Wow, that's kind of annoying. Well thank you for introducing me to .attrTween()!

Answer (score 12):

Here's what I think is going on: per [the SVG spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute), the transform

```
rotate(40 150,130)
```

is equivalent to:

```
translate(150,130) rotate(40) translate(-150, -130)
```

It looks like D3 is animating the translation as well as the rotation - the internal `d3.transform` representation of `rotate(40 150,130)` is a rotate component + a translation component, so both are being included in the transition.

The easiest fix here is to draw your needle at the origin, translate it with an outer `g` element to the correct position, then rotate it:

```
var needle = svg
  .append("g")
    .attr("class", "needle")
    .attr("transform", "translate(150 , 130)")
  .append("path")
    .attr("class", "tri")
    // your path may have been prettier
    .attr("d", "M-3 0 L0 -130 L3 0 S3 5 0 5 S-3 5 -3 0 Z")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-60)");
```

then

```
needle
    .transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .attr("transform", "rotate(40)");
```

See working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/74mCb/1/

Comment: Ah, so that's why it translates and rotates simultaneously! I always shrugged it off as a quirk.

Comment: Yeah, the last solution (redrawing the needle at the origin) is not just the easiest and most elegant, it's also the most appropriate. It's what one would do if animating the needle in any GUI tool (Flash, 3D editors etc).