# Strange rotation of rectangle around its center using d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I'm planning to rotate a rectangle around its center using d3.js.
My code is

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg").attr("width", 200).attr("height", 200).append("rect")
  .attr("x", 50)
  .attr("y", 50)
  .attr("fill", "black")
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 100)
  .transition()
  .ease("linear")
  .duration(1000)
  .attr("transform", "rotate(180,100,100)");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

It rotates and comes to its original x,y coordinates of rectangle, but
does not rotate around its center during rotation.

The correct code I found on web is

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 200).attr("height", 200);

var rect = svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 50)
    .attr("y", 50)
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100);

rect.transition().duration(5000)
    .attrTween("transform", rotTween);

function rotTween() {
    var i = d3.interpolate(0, 360);
    return function(t) {
        return "rotate(" + i(t) + ",100,100)";
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

This rectangle rotates around its center properly. But I can't see any difference between two codes. What's the difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [D3.js animate rotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313043/d3-js-animate-rotation)

Comment: In your example the tween will work on all the parameters that is rotation and translate. This is the reason why you get the swinging effect.
The rectangle is both translating and rotating. In the example you have put _return "rotate(" + i(t) + ",100,100)";_ you can see that only rotation angle is affected in the tween.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you can clearly see the difference when you check the attributes...

```js
var log = d3.ui.log("#log").style("vertical-align", "top"),
 logTween = d3.ui.log("#logTween").style("vertical-align", "top"),
    stoppedTween = false,
    stopped = false;
log.writeLine("translate\t\trotate")
logTween.writeLine("translate\t\trotate")

var rect = d3.select("body")
    .insert("svg", "#log").attr("width", 200).attr("height", 100).append("rect")
    .attr("x", 20)
    .attr("y", 20)
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("width", 40)
    .attr("height", 40);

rect.transition()
    .ease("linear")
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("transform", "rotate(180,100,100)")
    .each("start", function () {
    d3.timer(function () {
        var t = d3.transform(rect.attr("transform"));
        log.writeLine([t.translate.map(f).join(","), f(t.rotate)].join("\t"))
        return stopped;
    })
})
    .each("end", function () {
    stopped = true
});
var svg = d3.select("body").insert("svg", "#logTween").attr("width", 100).attr("height", 100);

var rectTween = svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 20)
    .attr("y", 20)
    .attr("width", 40)
    .attr("height", 40);


rectTween.transition().duration(1000)
    .ease("linear")
    .attrTween("transform", rotTween)
    .each("start", function () {
    d3.timer(function () {
        var t = d3.transform(rectTween.attr("transform"));
        logTween.writeLine([t.translate.map(f).join(","), f(t.rotate)].join("\t"))
        return stoppedTween;
    })
})
    .each("end", function () {
    stoppedTween = true
});


function rotTween() {
    var i = d3.interpolate(0, 360);
    return function(t) {
        return "rotate(" + i(t) + ",40,40)";
    };
}

function f(x) {
    return d3.format(" >6.1f")(x)
}
```

```css
div {white-space: pre;}
svg {overflow: visible;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/cool-Blue/d3-lib/master/Output/log/log.js"></script>
<div id="log"></div>
<div id="logTween"></div>
```