# Getting SVG transform to rotate on center

Tags: d3.js, svg

I'd like to rotate a d3 pack diagram on its axis just after open. I'm using transform `rotate(45 100 100)` on the `<g>` object. I believe I've set the center of the rotation properly (the circle begins and ends in the same place).

**Problem**: My circle pops out of alignment while spinning.

**CodePen**: https://codepen.io/denjn5/pen/wqgjMr

```
<style>
    circle {
        stroke: white;
        fill: #05668D;
        opacity: 0.3;
        stroke-width: 2px;
    }
</style>
<svg>
    <g></g>
</svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var vWidth = 200;
    var vHeight = 200;
    var vData = {
        'id': 'TOPICS', 'children': [{
            'id': 'Topic A',
            'children': [{'id': 'Sub A1', 'size': 4}, {'id': 'Sub A2', 'size': 4}]
        }, {
            'id': 'Topic C',
            'children': [{'id': 'Sub C1', 'size': 4}, {'id': 'Sub C2', 'size': 4}]
        }]};

    // Prepare our physical space
    var g = d3.select('svg').attr('width', vWidth).attr('height', vHeight).select('g');

    // Declare d3 layout
    var vLayout = d3.pack().size([vWidth, vHeight]);

    // Layout + Data
    var vRoot = d3.hierarchy(vData).sum(function (d) { return d.size; });
    var vNodes = vRoot.descendants();
    vLayout(vRoot);
    var vSlices = g.selectAll('circle').data(vNodes).enter().append('circle')
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
        .attr('r', function (d) { return d.r; });

    g.transition().duration(1000)
        .attr('transform', 'rotate(45 100 100)');
</script>
```

I see a few other posts about this topic. But they use non-SVG tags to solve or reference a browser bug (for good or bad, my code acts the same in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox). I appreciate your help.

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32410555/strange-rotation-of-rectangle-around-its-center-using-d3-js
The transition is working on both the rotate and translate.

Comment: Modifying your code to work like that linked duplicate looks like [this here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZJLNeb).

Comment: It works perfectly.  Thanks @TomShanley and @mark!