# Rotate a rect by its center in d3js version 7 (vs. version 4)

Tags: d3.js, rotation, version

With d3js v.4 I am able to rotate a rect around it's center. I've wrestled with doing this same effect using d3js v. 7 (or v5 and v6) to no avail. Can anyone show me in v.7 how to achieve what I'm doing with v.4 (code below)?
Sorry for not providing a jsFiddle. I've not practiced with it yet. But if you know d3js the following html page can be easily run locally if you have a simple server (such as VSCode LiveServer). Thanks for reading.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- Rotation behaves differently depending on d3js version -->
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script> -->
  <title>Works in D3.v4 but not D3.v5 or later</title>
  <style>
    svg {
      background:green;
    }

    svg rect {
      fill:purple
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    const svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
        .attr("height", 400)
        .attr("width", 400);

    const squareSize = 200;

    const group =  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(200, 200)");

    group.append("rect")
      .attr("width", squareSize)
      .attr("height", squareSize)
      .transition()
      .duration(8000)
      .attr("transform", "rotate(180)")
      .attr("y", -squareSize/2)
      .attr("x", -squareSize/2);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm seeing another example of successfully rotating a square around its center. But the explicit custom function seems like it shouldn't be needed by d3js. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32410555/strange-rotation-of-rectangle-around-its-center-using-d3-js

Comment: I take that back. In reviewing the d3js transition API docs I see that using custom attrTween function is an expected and normal practice. So I should probably answer my own question with a link to the above stackoverflow link. The api link is  https://devdocs.io/d3~5/d3-transition#transition_attrTween

Comment: No need for a tween function. Just set the `x` and `y` attributes before the transition. Otherwise they will be transitioned from `0` to `-squareSize/2`. I honestly don't know why v4 and v5/v6/v7 behave differently. Would have expected it otherwise, since there is nothing in the [changes.md](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/main/CHANGES.md) that indicates that.