# D3: Tumbling dice (unwantedly)

Tags: animation, d3.js, rotation

I want - with help of D3 - to rotate an object around its center with varying speed. Everything works fine as long as the **rotation speed isn't too high**. But eventually the **object starts tumbling** even though the rotation center is (visibly) fixed.

Find the tumbling dice at http://jsfiddle.net/mcqnpgn6/`

```
// initialize rotation angles
var dAngle = 10
var angles = []
var angle = 0;
for (i = 0; i < T; i++) {
  angles[i] = angle
  angle += dAngle > 0 ? dAngle : i
}

// create dice ....

// rotate dice
for (i = 0; i < T; i++) {
  dice.transition()
    .delay(i * dt)
    .duration(dt)
    .ease("linear")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(" + angles[i] + "," + cx + "," + cy + ")")
}
```

What did I do or understand wrongly? How would *you* solve this task?

Comment: I would use `requestAnimationFrame` instead of writing your own animation in a `for` loop, and I don't think this requires `transition()`.  Every frame, you want the die to rotate _some_ angle inversely related to the speed variable.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on my comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mcqnpgn6/25/. Key section below:

```
var theta = dAngle;

function rotate(){
  theta += dAngle;
  dice.attr("transform", "rotate(" + theta + "," + cx + "," + cy + ")")
  window.requestAnimationFrame(rotate);
}

rotate();
```

Comment: Thanks. Does requestAnimationFrame do the tweening? And do you have an explanation why my approach doesn't work for higher speeds?

Comment: There's no tweening with `requestAnimationFrame`, it's just rendering consecutive static frames at around ~60 fps.  

D3 `transition()` makes sense when your element has a fixed start and end position, less so for animation. (If you're going to repeat a transition, consult this example: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1125997). 

The reason for the tumbling becomes clearer if you make your `dAngle` large (try 500): D3 is interpolating the center of rotation so the element is being translated as well as rotated.

Comment: Thanks. What does "D3 is interpolating the center of rotation" mean? The center of rotation seems fixed to me.

Comment: Your rectangle has to pass through a bunch of other places to get from transform A to transform B, so it's making decisions about what those intermediary transforms will be. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313043/d3-js-animate-rotation