# Why does rotating element make it bounce?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've got an svg element and I'm adding a simple rotation attribute to it.
Problem is, I want the element to rotate relative to center of itself, not the whole svg, so I specify x and y for rotate, but it has a weird bouncy effect.

```js
let currentAngle = 0;

function rotate() {
  d3.select('.group1')
  .transition()
  .attr('transform', function() {
    let bb = this.getBBox();
    let rx = bb.x + bb.width / 2;
    let ry = bb.y + bb.height / 2;
    
    currentAngle += 90;
    
    return `rotate(${currentAngle}, ${rx}, ${ry})`;
    
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg viewbox="0 0 1600 1600" width="500" height="500">
  <g class="group1" onclick="rotate()">
    <rect x="250" y="250" width="100" height="100" />
    <circle cx="420" cy="300" r="50" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

As an alternative, I tried adding `transform-origin` on css, something like `transform-origin: 800px 800px;` (but with valid center px of course) and while it works in Chrome, it doesn't work in IE and Safari.

Why is supplying x and y on rotate making my element bounce?

Comment: Here is an example NOT using d3 that works http://jsfiddle.net/LukaszWiktor/haye1xj2/

Comment: I ended up using `gsap` for roation instead as it uses Matrix transformations which seems to work in IE 8.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few questions floating around that deal with this issue. Here's one that explains a bit what's going on: [D3.js animate rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313043/d3-js-animate-rotation)

The way Mike Bostock does it here: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3305854 is by placing the object in a `<g>` that is translated to the position you want and then rotating. This might be the easiest way to get a nice animation. For example:

```js
let currentAngle = 0;

function rotate() {
  d3.select('rect')
  .transition()
  .attr('transform', function() {
    let bb = this.getBBox();
    let rx = bb.x + bb.width / 2;
    let ry = bb.y + bb.height / 2;
    
    currentAngle += 45;
    
    return `rotate(${currentAngle}, ${rx}, ${ry})`;
    
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg viewbox="0 0 1600 1600" width="500" height="500">
<g transform="translate(250, 250)">
  <rect x="-50", y="-50" width="100" height="100" onclick="rotate()" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for that. The explanation makes sense (kind of) so thanks for that too. I simplified my scenario for the sake of this question, but I have a bunch of elements inside a group already, and I'm rotating the entire group. (I've updated my code snippet to better reflect my case) - I think I'm failing to translate your code to apply to the whole group. The `<g>` doesn't seem to want to stick to this above rule? Here is the code that shows my modification which adds another new `<g>`: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ayrdYg

Answer (score 1):

**LOOK AT THIS DIFFERENT**

if you `select` by `id` or by `class` and `rotate` it slowly, you will see the red dot in middle rotation move by little, but `select` by `id` i thing it more stable not like `select` by `class` it bouncing harder

```js
let currentAngle = 0;
let currentAngle2 = 0;

function rotate() {

  d3.select('#aa')
  
  .transition()
  .duration(300)
  .attr('transform', function() {
    let bb = this.getBBox();
    let rx = bb.x + bb.width / 2;
    let ry = bb.y + bb.height / 2;
         d3.select(this).append('circle')
    .attr('cx',rx)
    .attr('cy',ry)
    .attr('r',20)
    .attr('fill','red')
    currentAngle += 10;
    return `rotate(${currentAngle}, ${rx}, ${ry})`;
    
  });
}

function rotate2() {
  d3.selectAll('.aa')
  .transition()
  .attr('transform', function() {
    let bb = this.getBBox();
    let rx = bb.x + bb.width / 2;
    let ry = bb.y + bb.height / 2;
             d3.select(this).append('circle')
    .attr('cx',rx)
    .attr('cy',ry)
    .attr('r',20)
    .attr('fill','red')
    currentAngle2 += 10;
    return `rotate(${currentAngle2}, ${rx}, ${ry})`;
    
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




<svg viewbox="0 0 1600 1600" width="500" height="500">
<g id ='aa' onclick="rotate()">
  <rect x="100", y="100" width="100" height="100"  />
  <circle cx="250" cy="150" r="50"/>
</g>

<g class ='aa' onclick="rotate2()">
  <rect x="600", y="100" width="100" height="100"  />
  <circle cx="750" cy="150" r="50"  />
</g>

</svg>
```

then if you bouncing it with harsh value(big value) you will defintely see the red dot bouncing, but once again `select` by `id` doing more stable

```js
let currentAngle = 0;
let currentAngle2 = 0;

function rotate() {

  d3.select('#aa')
  
  .transition()
  .duration(300)
  .attr('transform', function() {
    let bb = this.getBBox();
    let rx = bb.x + bb.width / 2;
    let ry = bb.y + bb.height / 2;
         d3.select(this).append('circle')
    .attr('cx',rx)
    .attr('cy',ry)
    .attr('r',20)
    .attr('fill','red')
    currentAngle += 90;
    return `rotate(${currentAngle}, ${rx}, ${ry})`;
    
  });
}

function rotate2() {
  d3.selectAll('.aa')
  .transition()
  .attr('transform', function() {
    let bb = this.getBBox();
    let rx = bb.x + bb.width / 2;
    let ry = bb.y + bb.height / 2;
             d3.select(this).append('circle')
    .attr('cx',rx)
    .attr('cy',ry)
    .attr('r',20)
    .attr('fill','red')
    currentAngle2 += 90;
    return `rotate(${currentAngle2}, ${rx}, ${ry})`;
    
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




<svg viewbox="0 0 1600 1600" width="500" height="500">
<g id ='aa' onclick="rotate()">
  <rect x="100", y="100" width="100" height="100"  />
  <circle cx="250" cy="150" r="50"/>
</g>

<g class ='aa' onclick="rotate2()">
  <rect x="600", y="100" width="100" height="100"  />
  <circle cx="750" cy="150" r="50"  />
</g>

</svg>
```

**SOLUTION**

> you must make it slowly to rotated to end point, you can make tween
>   using `d3.interpolate`, and boom... it rotated perfecly by `id` or by
>   `class`

```js
let currentAngle = 0;
let currentAngle2 = 0;

function rotate() {

  d3.select('#aa')
  
  .transition()
  .duration(300)
  .attrTween("transform", tween);
  /*
  .attr('transform', function() {
    let bb = this.getBBox();
    let rx = bb.x + bb.width / 2;
    let ry = bb.y + bb.height / 2;
         d3.select(this).append('circle')
    .attr('cx',rx)
    .attr('cy',ry)
    .attr('r',20)
    .attr('fill','red')
    currentAngle += 10;
   // console.log(rx,ry,currentAngle)
   
    return `rotate(${currentAngle}, ${rx}, ${ry})`;
    
  });
  */

    function tween(d, i, a) {
        let bb = this.getBBox();
    let rx = bb.x + bb.width / 2;
    let ry = bb.y + bb.height / 2;
         d3.select(this).append('circle')
    .attr('cx',rx)
    .attr('cy',ry)
    .attr('r',20)
    .attr('fill','red')
    var e = `rotate(${currentAngle}, ${rx}, ${ry})`
    currentAngle += 90;
    var o = `rotate(${currentAngle}, ${rx}, ${ry})`
      return d3.interpolateString(e,o);
    }

  

}

function rotate2() {

  d3.selectAll('.aa')
  .transition()
  .duration(300)
  .attrTween("transform", tween);
  /*
  .attr('transform', function() {
    let bb = this.getBBox();
    let rx = bb.x + bb.width / 2;
    let ry = bb.y + bb.height / 2;
             d3.select(this).append('circle')
    .attr('cx',rx)
    .attr('cy',ry)
    .attr('r',20)
    .attr('fill','red')
    currentAngle2 += 10;
   // console.log(rx,ry,currentAngle)
   
    return `rotate(${currentAngle2}, ${rx}, ${ry})`;
    
  });
  */
  
  function tween(d, i, a) {
        let bb = this.getBBox();
    let rx = bb.x + bb.width / 2;
    let ry = bb.y + bb.height / 2;
         d3.select(this).append('circle')
    .attr('cx',rx)
    .attr('cy',ry)
    .attr('r',20)
    .attr('fill','red')
    var e = `rotate(${currentAngle2}, ${rx}, ${ry})`
    currentAngle2 += 90;
    var o = `rotate(${currentAngle2}, ${rx}, ${ry})`
      return d3.interpolateString(e,o);
    }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




<svg viewbox="0 0 1600 1600" width="500" height="500">
<g id ='aa' onclick="rotate()">
  <rect x="100", y="100" width="100" height="100"  />
  <circle cx="250" cy="150" r="50"/>
</g>

<g class ='aa' onclick="rotate2()">
  <rect x="600", y="100" width="100" height="100"  />
  <circle cx="750" cy="150" r="50"  />
</g>

</svg>
```